# react native project recovery after my hard drive crash

Tags: javascript, react-native

My React Native project was gone due to a hard drive crash.i have already tried to recover but my js file not comming properly. Is there any way to get back my project file?

Comment: have you connected with git repo ?

Comment: no that is the problem. not back up anywhere